# Add hyperlink text to Excel cell

Tags: c#, excel, hyperlink

I'm trying to format the text in a cell, which is a valid URL, as hypertext programmatically. When one inserts a text to a cell in Excel, it automatically creates a hyperlink formatted by default as underlined blue text.

When I google I can only find the following C# code:

```
worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Hyperlink = "www.example.com";
```

But this is not exactly what I want. This makes the cell act as a hyperlink and does not change the format of the text.

Is there any way to create a text hyperlink in Excel programmatically?

Answer (score -1):

create a hyperlink on notepad, save the document with .html extension, run it in a browser, copy the hyperlink text from the browser and paste in the excel or any other document like Word.

```
<a href="">Sample Text</a>
```

the page you want to link to should be inside the quotation mark